# Are advanced search operators supported on SxA search components?

Tags: sxa, content-search

Are advanced search operators supported by the SxA out of the box search components? If so, where can I find documentation on the syntax?

AND, OR, Exclude and "exact match" is what I am looking for, nothing more sophisticated than that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The SXA search renderings don't allow to modify the query on such a low level. If you would like to modify the query which is built you need to override `SearchService`. It shouldn't be hard to do that as this service is registered in the DI container, but modifying SXA queries might not be the best idea because:

- modifying the query might break SXA logic - e.g.: in geo-search queries we expect certain data to be returned
- when using boosting the query need to have certain syntax and specific set of conditions - changing that might break boosted order of results
- modifications to the query might break Search Box logic - search box is looking for content in the `AggregatedContent` computed field

I can provide a few more examples of what can go wrong if you will modify the query build in SXA.

Comment: I hear you. Can you expand on why modifying SXA queries might not be the best idea? What drawbacks/pitfalls you envisage?

Comment: @PedroFonseca I've updated my comment with few examples.

Comment: Excellent Dawid. Thanks.